# Manually input date in edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, user-input

I want to manually (i.e. from the numeric keyboard) input date in dd-mm-yyyy format in an edittext field. Also to assign three integer variables, day, month, year for another calculation in such a way that the first two characters (i.e. index 0, 1) be the day variable then automatically add a separator ("-' or "/") then next two digit should be month variable then an automated separator like before and finally year. The day and month should display as two digit with leading zero (if necessary). Also if the user enter 4-9 in day field at index zero(0) it automatically convert it into two digit and move to month field, also for month 2-9 make that two digit and move to year. Finally when the input process completes move the cursor to next edittext field.
I apologize for my poor English.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this. Certain edge cases are not handled. Do those.

```
 private static final char SEPERATOR = '-';

    private void automateDateEntry() {
        dateEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.length() > 10) {
                    charSequence = charSequence.subSequence(0, 10);
                    dateEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    dateEditText.setText(charSequence);
                    dateEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String currText = editable.toString();
                if(currText.isEmpty())
                    return;
                int separatorCount = getOcurrence(currText, SEPERATOR);

                if (currText.charAt(currText.length() - 1) == SEPERATOR) {
                    return;
                }
                int lastSeperatorPos = currText.lastIndexOf(SEPERATOR);
                String previousTxt = null;
                if (lastSeperatorPos > -1) {
                    previousTxt = currText.substring(0, lastSeperatorPos + 1);
                    Log.d("curr text", currText);
                    currText = currText.substring(lastSeperatorPos + 1);
                }

                if (!currText.isEmpty()) {
                    switch (separatorCount) {
                        case 0:
                            int date = Integer.parseInt(currText);
                            if (date < 0 || date > 31) {
                                dateEditText.setError("Enter proper date");
                                return;
                            }
                            if (currText.length() == 2 || date >= 4) {
                                currText = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", date);
                                currText += SEPERATOR;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1: int month = Integer.parseInt(currText);
                            if (month < 0 || month > 31) {
                                dateEditText.setError("Enter proper month");
                                return;
                            }
                            if (currText.length() == 2 || month >= 2) {
                                currText = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", month);
                                currText += SEPERATOR;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2: int year = Integer.parseInt(currText);
                            if (year < 0 ) {
                                dateEditText.setError("Enter proper year");
                                return;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if(previousTxt != null){
                    currText = previousTxt + currText;
                }
                dateEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                dateEditText.setText(currText);
                int textLength = currText.length();
                dateEditText.setSelection(textLength, textLength);
                dateEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        });
    }

    private int getOcurrence(String string, char ch) {
        int count = 0;
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (string.charAt(i) == ch)
                ++count;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Debanjan. That was very helpful. But there is a little problem. When I try to print the variables in a text view all the variables have value zero. Any suggestion?

Comment: which variables? Most of them are integers, so to print them, you should use String.valueOf(month), like this.

Comment: Accept or upvote it, if this serves your purpose. Welcome.

Comment: The variable print issue solved. Actually I had to put that printing code inside an onClickListener. Now if I want to edit a particular variable, can you help me on that issue @Debanjan. I am very beginner in this field. How do I accept your suggestions? Do I have to comment as "ACCEPTED"? Thank you for your time and cooperation.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, just click on the tick beside the answer.

Comment: Suppose I have entered a wrong day/month and now I am entering 2nd digit of year in edittext2 field. Now If I press the (×) button, I am unable to go beyond the last separator. If I want to edit the day/month field, I have to click that field. All I want is that I only touch the (×) button and it smoothly will take me to my desired place by deleting the previous characters. Also when the year input in et2 is complete, the cursor automatically moves to the first position of et2. I want the cursor to remain at the position where I completed i.e after the last digit of yyyy. Is it possible?

Comment: You have to do that yourself. Tweak the logic a bit, you'll be able to do that

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to generate a new view which extends an EditText and overrite the onkeyup method.
Each time you have entered a key you can get the text, analyse it and change it to your needs.